# DatagridViewRow.Cells.Add method is not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows forms in which I have this DataGridView in this I am trying to loop through all the DataGridView rows to add a comboboxcell after two columns .

My goal is to have a combo box column which shows items based on value of cell[0].

Here is my code and I am not able to add any cells to the DataGridView row. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void UserAccessForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = LoadData();
    AddPermissions();

}

private DataTable LoadData()
{
    ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserProfile"].ToString();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        // Create the command and set its properties
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // Assign the SQL to the command object
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = string.Format(Script.sqlGetLocalSystem);

    
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;
}

public void AddPermissions()
{
    DataTable dPermissions = new DataTable();
    long systemId = 0;

    
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBoxCell = null;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        ArrayList permissions = new ArrayList();
        comboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        systemId = Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[0].Value);
        dPermissions = LoadPermissions(systemId);
        
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dPermissions.Rows)
        {
            permissions.Add(dataRow["UserLevelCategoryName"].ToString());
        }
        comboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(permissions.ToArray());

        row.Cells.Add(comboBoxCell);

    }
}
```

How do I accomplish this ?

Comment: You should add `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to `Columns` collection of `DataGridView`.

Comment: Thank you , yea I get your point. I tried your solution, but the problem is the event dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing is not getting fired , because I dont have to change anything in the datagrid... automatically when the datagrid is loaded I want the combobox also to be loaded... Hope I am clear this time

Comment: The first problem is you are adding cell to cells collection of grid. **It is wrong!** You can add a combobox column the way which I described in answer. Then ask a new question about how to have different items in combo boxes.

Comment: ok yea got it.. thanks for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add cell to cells collection of a row.You should add [`DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to `Columns` collection of `DataGridView` and set the list as [`DataSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.datasource?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).aspx) of the column. Also set [`DisplayMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.displaymember?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to a field of data source to show in combo, and set [`ValueMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.valuemember?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to a field of data source to use its value as selected value when you choose an item from combo.

If your grid control is also bound to a data source and you are creating this column to show the value of a field from data source of the grid, set [`DataPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) of your column to a filed of grid data source which you want to bind this column to it.

```
DataTable permissions = LoadPermissions(); //Load all permissions
var column1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
column1.Name = "column1";
column1.DataSource = permissions;

//a column from Permissions table to use its value when the user select from combo box
column1.ValueMember = "Id";  

//a column from Permissions table to show its value in combo box
column1.DisplayMember = "Name"; 

//a column from datasourec table of your grid which you want to bind column to
column1.DataPropertyName = "PermissionId";

//Add column to grid 
this.categoryDataGridView.Columns.Add(column1);
```

Then if you want to show different items in combo box of each row based on another cell, you should handle [`EditingControlShowing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event and get the editing control and set `DataSource` of the control based on value of the other cell.